# Blob, Decimal, Linestring type in Aqueduct

Tags: dart, aqueduct

I'm creating a POC to migrate an existing MySQL database to Postgres and use Aqueduct as backend. In MySQL I have following attributes, which I'm currently unsure, how to use them in Aqueduct in combination with Postgres:

- **Blob:** Would I use String as dart type, and then set databaseType to
  Blob? Or can I use Byte as dart type? This would be preferred.
- **Decimal:** Would I use String as dart type and then set
  databaseType to Decimal?
- **LineString:** In Postgres this relates to TYPE GEOMETRY(POINT,xxxx). Any way to read and store this through Aqueduct?
- **Enum:** In the database i can see enums with hyphens and even with spaces. And one enum has the word "new" which dart has a problem with. How would I be able to use these?
- **Set:** I can also see, that SET is used, which can set multiple values. Any idea how I could model these?

Anyway I hope I can just create the database with enum and set manually, and then use String to save the values. I hope the same works with point geometry. For Blob I hope byte works.